# Android app with remote service

Tags: java, android, service, aidl

I have created an android app with a remote service with aidl based on this tutorial:

http://www.anddev.org/remote_service_tutorial-t8127.html

I changed the service so that it prints a counter to logcat to show that it is running.

```
class Task implements Runnable {
    private final ResultReceiver receiver2;

    public Task(ResultReceiver receiver) {
        receiver2 = receiver;
    }

    public void run() {

        while (true) {
            ++counter;

            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            try {
                System.out.println("Server counter: " + counter);
                // get some data or something
                b.putInt("results", counter);
                receiver2.send(STATUS_FINISHED, b);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                b.putString(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, e.toString());
                receiver2.send(STATUS_ERROR, b);
            }

            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            // serviceHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000L);
            Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Incrementing counter in the run method");
        }
    }
}
```

I wanted to check that the service continued to run even when main app stopped, so i used finish() to "kill" the activity. The counter continious to be printed to logcat even when the activity is gone.

When I reopen the app. I click the start button and use the following code to check if the service is running (which it is, I can see the counter running in logcat) **but it does not exist** in the list with running services.

I want to know if the service is running. If it's running, then I want to bind the app to the existing service. If not, a new service should be started.

public class ServiceTools {
    private static String LOG_TAG = ServiceTools.class.getName();

```
public static boolean isServiceRunning(Context context, String serviceClassName) {
    final ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for (RunningServiceInfo info : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
        String name = info.service.getClassName();
        if (name.equals(serviceClassName)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
 }
```

}

And now my questions: Why is my service not in Running services? Can I bind to a service even if it is not in the running services collection?

Answer (score 2):

I just want to say that on my device the method you stated for telling whether a Service is running does not work (it will always return false). I know, I tried the same thing for one of my Services. In the documentation for the [getRunningServices()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getRunningServices%28int%29) method it is stated it should actually not be used by apps.

Also, what I conclude based on your story is that the Service probably does get stopped/killed, but its process is still alive, because that thread it started is still alive and working. So you probably are right, the Service stopped, but the Thread lives on. Do you use stopService() or unbindService() in any of your code? If there hasn't been a call to startService() before binding, the Service will stop after all its clients have called unbindService()...